# What do the difficulty levels do in Sir Benfro’s Brilliant Balloon?

Tags: sir-benfros-brilliant-balloon

In Sir Benfro’s Brilliant Balloon, (a free adventure game on iOS), there are three difficulty levels:

- Beginner Balloonist
- Brilliant Balloonist
- Bonkers Balloonist

What are the differences between each difficulty level?

Answer (score -1):

From what I found, **the difficulty levels make it easier or harder to pass through a level**. [NBC an article about Sir Benfro's Brilliant Balloon.](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/47209193/ns/technology_and_science-tech_and_gadgets/#.WjRALt-nGUk)

The following quote is what led me to believe this.

> Some parts of each stage do get tough, but you can control that by choosing from adjustable difficulty settings — from Beginner to Bonkers.